include a tree diagram (qtree) in a figure environment
I have the following WME it works fine but when I uncomment out the lines to put it in a figure environment it will not compile.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

%\begin{figure}[h]
%\centering
\Tree [.Quadrilaterals 
        [.Parallelograms 
            [.Rectangular square oblong ]
            [.Non-rectangular rhombus rhomboid ]
        ]
        [.Non-parallelograms 
            [.{Two sides parallel \\ (trapezium)} isosceles trapezium scalene trapezium ]
            [.{No sides parallel \\ (trapezoid)} ]
        ]
      ]
%\end{figure}

\end{document}

with he following error.
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.22 \end
         {figure}
? 

Is qtree not compatible with figure?

There is no problem with figure but \centering changes the definition of \\  and that generates errors on your use of \\  within the tree, whether or not you use figure.
As the figure is wider than the page
Overfull \hbox (142.74435pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 20--28
\centering does nothing useful anyway so:

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
%\centering
\Tree [.Quadrilaterals 
        [.Parallelograms 
            [.Rectangular square oblong ]
            [.Non-rectangular rhombus rhomboid ]
        ]
        [.Non-parallelograms 
            [.{Two sides parallel \\ (trapezium)} isosceles trapezium scalene trapezium ]
            [.{No sides parallel \\ (trapezoid)} ]
        ]
      ]
\end{figure}

\end{document}


Thanks, can I ask you, just out of interest what \centering does to \?

@PaulA it makes it make a short but centred line rather than the usual short left aligned line. (basically \\  does \hfill\linebreak  which does the right thing in a normal justified paragraph but would mess up centering.
